# Limit of ratio of exponential function as variable tends to infinity:$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{e^{x^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Could someone please point out resources or provide the solution with detailed steps to calculate the following limits?

If possible, please provide solutions with or without using L'Hopital's rule.

$$
\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left[\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x^{2}}}\right]
$$

Thanks,

Comment: For the solution with L'Hospital's rule, you should first try to calculate it yourself!

Comment: @5xum I tried with L'Hospital's rule but the denominator keeps growing ... Have you seen this problem solved using this technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need using l'Hospital here, for 
$$ \frac{e^x}{e^{x^2}} = e^{x-x^2} $$
And now $\lim_{x \to \infty} x-x^2 = -\infty$, that is, 
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^{x^2}} = \lim_{y \to -\infty} e^y = 0 $$

---

Addendum: We will show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} (x-x^2) = -\infty$. For $x \ge 1$, we have 
$$ x-x^2 = x(1-x) \le 1-x $$
If now $L \ge 0$ is given, for $x \ge \max\{1,L+1\}$, we have
$$ x-x^2 \le 1-x \le 1-(L+1) = -L $$
as $L$ was arbitrary, $x-x^2 \to -\infty$.

Comment: could you please clarify how $x-x^{2}$ tends to negative infinity ?

Comment: @user249613 Added something.

Comment: what a wonderful proof .... Much appreciated thanks

Comment: One simple clarification, do we take $x \ge \max\{1,L+1\}$ since $x$ tends to infinity?

Comment: Right. $\lim_{x\to\infty} (x-x^2) = -\infty$ means that 
$$ \forall L \ge 0\, \exists x_0 \, \forall x \ge x_0: x-x^2 \le -L $$
we have $x_0 = \max\{1, L+1\}$ here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by writting $$\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x^2}} = e^{x-x^2}=e^{-x(x-1)}$$ you get that the limit is $0$ since $-x(x-1)\to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{e^{x}}{e^{x^2}} = e^{x-x^2}$$